# How do you get the 'Target type' of a shortcut

Tags: vbscript

I want to delete all shortcuts in the desktop folder, and ensure that a clean set of shorcuts is added.

However, I need to keep shorcuts to mapped drives. If you look at the 'Shortcut' tab of the 'Properties', you can see that shortcuts of this type have the `Target type` of 'File Folder'.

The problem is, I cannot find any way of accessing the target type through VBS. I can get the type (`objFile.Type`), but that gives you the `Type of file` on the 'General' tab (in this case, 'Shortcut').

Does anybody know for a way of accessing the `Target type`? Thanks.

```
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files

    ' Check that the file 'Target type' is not 'File Folder'
    If Not objFile.Type = "File Folder" Then
        objFSO.DeleteFile(desktop_locations(i) & objFile.Name)
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check the target of the shortcut:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

shortcut = "C:\path\to\some.lnk"

Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(shortcut)
If Not fso.FolderExists(lnk.TargetPath) Then
  'target doesn't exist or is not a folder
  fso.DeleteFile shortcut
End If
```